# How can I add markers in ResourceChangeListener (eclipse plugin)?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I need to highlight the text using the marker and annotation.
I can highlight the text after file activated (`IPartListener2`) but I need to highlight this text after the user save the file (`IResourceChangeListener`).

I am using the following code for adding markers,

```
private void updateMarkers2(IResource resource) throws PartInitException {
    IEditorPart editorPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .getActiveEditor();
    if (editorPart != null) {
        FileEditorInput input = (FileEditorInput) editorPart
                .getEditorInput();
        IFile file = input.getFile();
        IEditorDescriptor desc = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getName());
        FileEditorInput fileEditorInput = new FileEditorInput(file);
        ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().openEditor(fileEditorInput, desc.getId());
        IDocumentProvider dp = editor.getDocumentProvider();
        IDocument doc = dp.getDocument(fileEditorInput);

        IMarker marker = null;
        try {
            resource.deleteMarkers("org.eclipse.marker.value.id", true, 1);

            final IRegion region = doc.getLineInformation(77);
            marker = resource.createMarker("org.eclipse.marker.value.id");
            //marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, 77);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, region.getOffset());
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, region.getOffset() + region.getLength());
        } catch (CoreException | BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting following exception:

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: The resource tree is locked for modifications.
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2188)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.deleteMarkers(Resource.java:821)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add markers or make any other changes to resources in the actual `IResourceChangeListener` as the workspace is locked and changes are not allowed.

Build up a list of markers you want to set in the listener and then submit a `WorkspaceJob` to make the changes. This should run after the lock is released.